# I need to make a stored procedure run in batch

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a procedure that  updates over  2000 rows in a table.

I need to make the procedure run in batch. I want it to run on the first 10 rows then the next ten and so on. Please how do i go about it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What is the actual goal? Are you finding that when you update all 2000 rows (which is tiny, btw) there are performance issues? Maybe folks could take a look at your update statement for possible optimizations, instead of jumping to conclusions about what the solution must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
declare @id int
declare c cursor for 
  select top 10 id 
  from table 
  where (needs updating) = 1

open c 
fetch next from c into @id
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

  update table 
  set 
    (needs to be set) = (value to set), 
    (needs updating) = 0      
  where id = @id

  fetch next from c into @id

end
```